# Ruby line break when using rails jquery autocomplete gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using jQuery autocomplete on a search field in my application. The field searches and returns an address as an hash. I need to add a line break between the hash values, but nothing I do is working.

In my controller I have:

```
autocomplete :restaurant, :name, :display_value => :funky_method, :extra_data => [:id, :address, :city, :state, :zip_code`]
```

in my model I have:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('id @@ ?', search)
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

In my model I tried the following:

```
def funky_method
  "#{self.id}" + "\n" + "#{self.name}" + "\n" + "#{self.address}" + "\n" + "#{self.city}" + "\n"  + "#{self.state}" + "\n" + "#{self.zip_code}"
end
```

and:

```
def funky_method
  "#{self.id}" + "<br />" + "#{self.name}" + "<br />" + "#{self.address}" + "<br />" + "#{self.city}" + "<br />"  + "#{self.state}" + "<br />" + "#{self.zip_code}"
end
```

and:

```
def funky_method
  "#{self.id}" + <br /> + "#{self.name}" + <br /> + "#{self.address}" + <br /> + "#{self.city}" + <br />  + "#{self.state}" + <br /> + "#{self.zip_code}"
end
```

In my view i have:

```
<%= form_tag users_path do %>
    <p>Please select a restaurant First</p>
        <%= autocomplete_field_tag :search, params[:search], autocomplete_restaurant_name_users_path, :value_method => :id %>
            <%= submit_tag "Next", :name => nil, :id => "submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, HTML doesn't, and browsers don't, honor line-breaks outside of `<textarea>` blocks, or inside a `<pre>` block.

You have to use `<br>` instead of "\n" or wrap the individual lines in `<p>` tags or embed your output into one of the above. You can set a textarea to "readonly" to turn off editing in the block.

You can do that on the Ruby/server side, or have jQuery do it prior to insertion into the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `html_safe`:

```
  def funky_method
    "#{self.id} <br /> #{self.name} <br /> #{self.address} <br /> #{self.city} <br /> #{self.state} <br /> #{self.zip_code}".html_safe
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of other ways to achieve this:

**Join with `\n`** and `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper`(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) module.  This method appends a `<br />` tag after every `\n` found but does not remove it.

```
def funky_method
  simple_format([ self.id, self.name, self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zip_code ].join('\n'))
end
```

Or without the `TextHelper` module as above:

**Join by `<br />`**

```
def funky_method
  [ self.id, self.name, self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zip_code ].join('<br />').html_safe
end
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried all the variations here, but each one only appends the string "<br />" in the line so that it shows up as "id<br />name<br />address<br />city<br />state<br />zip" I added whats in my view if that helps.